# F5 Does not start debugging in Azure Cloud Shell

Tags: node.js, azure, debugging, azure-cloud-shell

I am following the Azure learning path on Microsoft's website. One of the modules requires starting a node.js application with Azure Cloud Shell. I followed all the steps on the module with no issue, until trying to press F5 to start debugging. If I press F5 when the cursor is on the command line, ~ is added to the command line. If I press F5 when the cursor is not on the command line, the page just refreshed and I have to start over. I tried this on both Microsoft Edge and Chrome, both have the same behavior. Any idea on how I can start debugging? Desperate for help (Have to use Azure Cloud Shell in order to get access to the free azure resources)

This is the link to the learning module:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/automatic-update-of-a-webapp-using-azure-functions-and-signalr/3-exercise-analyze-limitations-of-polling-in-a-web-app?source=learn

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have tested the same in my VS Code and its working fine , Following are the steps to be followed to debug the function app that you have . And we can not debug by hitting F5 in our azure cloud shell.

By following [MS  DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/automatic-update-of-a-webapp-using-azure-functions-and-signalr/3-exercise-analyze-limitations-of-polling-in-a-web-app) ,Hope you have already installed this in your local:

- [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/download/)
- [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/download)
- [Azure Functions Core Tools](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools)
- [Azure Functions extension for Visual Studio Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-azuretools.vscode-azurefunctions)
- [Azure Storage extension for Visual Studio Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-azuretools.vscode-azurestorage)
- [Azure Account extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure-stack/user/azure-stack-dev-start-vscode-azure?view=azs-2102)  in your VS Code.

And install [GitBash](https://git-scm.com/download/win) in your local and turn on your IIS express from control panel . And
Then run the same command in your VS code and  install NPM  .

[image]

Go to Run & debug section as on screenshot and add one `launch.json` file and then hit F5 to debug your function app .
Here are some screenshots for reference:

[image]

[image]

After that from your gitbash run the npm start cmd which will gives you the **Output**
as below:

[image]

**NOTE:**

> Based on the following MS DOC beginning state of the app is located
> in the **start** folder. Make sure you are in that folder for the rest
> of this module. Run the following command to open the *start* folder
> in Visual Studio Code

You can refer this for more information: [Debugging in Visual studio code](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/debugging).

Answer (score 0):

Let me see if I understand this.  I post clearly stated questions about the previous posting, and these are not clear enough for you.